# Where clause only returning a subset of products matching index array

Tags: c#, indexing, where-clause, ienumerable

I have a list of ordered products. I also have a list of index values. I want to pull out all products whose index is in the list of indexes. Right now I'm doing this:

```
var indexes = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 };
var myProducts = orderedProducts.Where((pr, i) => indexes.Any(x => x == i)).ToList();
```

However, myProducts only has 2 elements in it: The products with indexes 1 and 2. It completely misses 5, 7, and 10. What is going on? How do I fix this?

Note: `orderedProducts.Count` is always greater than the maximum value of the `indexes` list.

`orderedProducts` is formed from the following:

```
orderedProducts = productDictionary[fam.Key]
.ToList()
.OrderBy(g => g.factor)
.ToList();
```

where `g.factor` is an int, `fam.Key` is an int key for the product dictionary. I've checked myProducts and it is indeed a `List<Product>` ordered by factor ascending.

`prodDictionary` is a `Dictionary<int?, List<Product>>`.

Comment: sure that `i` is the ordinal (zero-based) index in your `orderedProducts` dictionary and not an arbitrary database key?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `orderedProducts` and the resulting `myProducts`.  Also you could just do `indexes.Contains(i)` and you might want to use a `HashSet<int>` instead if performance is ever an issue.

Comment: This does not reproduce. `myProducts` **contains all 5 items** when I add this line to the beginning of your sample code: `var orderedProducts = Enumerable.Range(1, 20);` Please add a line of code that populates `orderedProducts` in such a way that your code reproduces the problem so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Also you don't happen to have any other `Where` calls before that one in your actual code do you?  If so, it should be noted that the index will be from the filtered results and not the original source.

Comment: Ah crap. I just realized my error. The code that spawns indexes is incorrect. facepalm.

Comment: I wrote the question, and I just realized where the error is and it is unrelated. Please close it. Or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed something in your testing. You said "`myProducts.Count` is always greater than the maximum value of the indexes list". That makes no sense considering you said "myProducts only has 2 elements". `orderedProducts.Count` must be < 6. Thus the problem. You are pulling out elements by simply comparing the indexes in the List. You can "fix" the problem by adding more products to the list.

```
void Main()
{
    var indexes = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 };

    var orderedProducts = new List<Product>();

    orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());//Add this in and you will see a result at index 5
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());//7
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());
    //orderedProducts.Add(new Product());//10

    var myProducts = orderedProducts.Where((pr, i) => indexes.Any(x => x == i)).ToList();
}

public class Product
{
}
```

Uncomment the products and you get 5 results as expected.  Index of 10 on a 0 based array.

Comment: I apologise for the typo. I meant orderedProducts is always greater than the max of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

why not just `indexes.Where(i => i < orderedProducts.Count).Select(i => orderedProducts[i]).ToList();`?